# How to decrease the count of life after each turn using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, if-statement

I have been developing a memory game and it working perfect. I wanted to add a life function in the game where after each wrong match , the player loses one of the hearts on the screen . I have attached the image below:

[image]

What i have achieved till now is, when i make the first unmatch, the life decrease by one but after that there is no decrease in life. I have attached the snippet code below :

```
function unmatched() {
openedCards[0].classList.add("unmatched");
openedCards[1].classList.add("unmatched");

    life();
}

 function life(){
    for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
     if(i=4) {
      starElementsArray[i].style.opacity = 0.1;
      }
    }
 }
```

In the above code, when the function unmatch is executed it checks for the life function where the life is inside the array and i m reducing the opacity of one heart. when i make the first unmatch, it works , but after that I could not reduce the opacity of other hearts one by one. I m kin of stuck in this iteration part. Can someone help me fix this .

Comment: what does `disable` do?

Comment: @Luka i edited the code now, the disable function is not required for this code

Comment: do you have some kind of variable where you save how many lives are left?

Comment: @Luka no, i dont store it in any variable.

Comment: What is function `life` supposed to do? Remove one life? Or refresh the hearts on the screen? Or something else? I suggest you to name functions more precisely. If this function is supposed to only refresh the hears, maybe you can call it `refreshLives`. The same goes for `unmatched`

Comment: If you don't store it in a variable, how do you know at some point how many lives are left?

Comment: @Luka ahhh yes, i understand now . thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that because you define your life in the function, every time you call the life() function, its like resetting your life... and then looping.. continuously till i=4 and then decreasing opacity of square 4.

You need to store life outside the function and then you dont need to loop at all.. just reduce

```
var currentLife = 4;

function life(){
    starElementsArray[currentLife].style.opacity = 0.1;
    currentLife--;
    if(currentLife < 0){
        // do whatever happens when they run out of life because it continuously decreases as life() is ran
    }
}
```

Comment: This works too. He's stating instead of starting at your current `i = 0` ... do `i = X`. X being your max time and also decrement instead of increment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend utilizing `setTimeout()` to invoke once the user gets a wrong answer and reset it when they get it right.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout